# Best way to monitor server performance in real time

Tags: server

I have multiplayer server written in C that handles various tasks like user sessions, game states and database. The server communicates with clients via TCP sockets. There are multiple threads each handling their own job, like accepting new connections, turning stream bytes into messages, updating game state, delivering messages to respective game state instances.

I want to have some kind of monitor that would show me performance of this server. For example how long did it take for game updating thread to advance game state by one step. Or how much users are currently handled by messaging thread. I want to see it in real time on remote device.

So far I have 2 ideas. One is to have some special client that can send special message, and then the server starts sending him back messages every second with all desired data. The client can be just simple dashboard UI. Other way would be to activate monitoring during server startup with command line arguments and then the server saves all the desired data to database every second. Then the dashboard client just connects to database and retrieves it every second.

Which one is better? Or is there better way?

Comment: Both your approaches sound like they'd work just fine. Have you encountered any difficulty making either one work for your needs?

Comment: I didnt try either yet. Im just trying to figure out pros and cons and the best approach overall.